# Sql Server find a geometry in a set of geometries

Tags: sql-server-2008, gis, spatial

i have list of geometries of latitude and longitude in a table.

can i write a query on states table(also geometry here) to find the state in which that 
lat-long is present.

thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the [STIntersects method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933899.aspx)?

Be sure the SRID's match, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH StreetsGeometry (streetsid, streetgeosegment)
AS
(SELECT S.[UniqueID], S.[GEOSEGMENT] 
 FROM [dbo].[StreetsDB] S )

SELECT S.streetsid, A.UniqueID
FROM [dbo].[newStreetsDB] AS A, StreetsGeometry S
WHERE A.GEOCOORD.STContains(S.streetgeosegment) = 1
```

This may help you